# Snowflake: Perfomance is slow with millions of rows

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Requirement: To Speed up the performance in snowflake

Issue: It's taking a lot of time even to read data, Has created a cluster in the table for the columns as

```
create or replace TABLE table_A cluster by (ID, yyyymm)(
YYYYMM NUMBER(38,0),
ID NUMBER(38,0),
.....(lot of other columns)
......
SURROGATE_KEY VARCHAR(16777216)
```

);

Table has `70,825,139,352 rows`

If the ID was inserted into the table recently in the last 60 mins, we want to delete any previous version of that ID if it's in the last 3 months

Below is the query

```
select
  surrogate_key,
  SUBSTR(surrogate_key, 1, CHARINDEX('|', surrogate_key) - 1)::bigint as original_id,
  array_agg(distinct yyyymm) as yyyymms,
  max(extraction_ts) as max_extraction_ts
from table A
where (ID, surrogate_key) IN (
  select ID, surrogate_key from table A where create_time >= dateadd(minute, -60, current_timestamp)
)
and yyyymm >= to_char(dateadd(month, -3, current_timestamp), 'YYYYMM')::bigint
and yyyymm <= to_char(dateadd(month, -0, current_timestamp), 'YYYYMM')::bigint
group by surrogate_key
;
```

Then I tried to just get rows for last 3 months , even this is taking lot of time

```
    select yyyymm, ID, 
 surrogate_key,create_time,extraction__ts
  from table A
 where yyyymm >= to_char(dateadd(month, -3, current_timestamp), 'YYYYMM')::bigint
   and yyyymm <= to_char(dateadd(month, -0, current_timestamp), 'YYYYMM')::bigint
```

When I checked the query explain plan ,looks like its scanning entire table instead of only those filtered data

[image]

I am not sure how to optimize the query performance, I am missing something here

I also found out that as below it was taking more time to scan entire partitions

```
Pruning 
275,445 Partitions scanned 
945,526 Partitions total –
```

> EDIT: UPDATED

I now tried with clause somewhat faster than the original query but still takes 9 mins to get the data

```
with tbl as (select ID, surrogate_key from table A where create_time >= dateadd(minute, -60, current_timestamp))
select
      surrogate_key,
      SUBSTR(surrogate_key, 1, CHARINDEX('|', surrogate_key) - 1)::bigint as original_id,
      array_agg(distinct yyyymm) as yyyymms,
      max(extraction_ts) as max_extraction_ts
    from table A
    where (ID, surrogate_key) IN (select ID, surrogate_key from tbl)
    and yyyymm >= to_char(dateadd(month, -3, current_timestamp), 'YYYYMM')::bigint
    and yyyymm <= to_char(dateadd(month, -0, current_timestamp), 'YYYYMM')::bigint
    group by surrogate_key
    ;
```

I tried changing the cluster key as suggested by Eric Lin but same time it took

**> EDIT: Output of system$clustering_information**

**Original : (ID,yyymm)**

```
 {
  "cluster_by_keys" : "LINEAR(ID, yyyymm)",
  "total_partition_count" : 946321,
  "total_constant_partition_count" : 766438,
  "average_overlaps" : 57.6508,
  "average_depth" : 30.1231,
  "partition_depth_histogram" : {
    "00000" : 0,
    "00001" : 764362,
    "00002" : 0,
    "00003" : 0,
    "00004" : 0,
    "00005" : 0,
    "00006" : 0,
    "00007" : 0,
    "00008" : 0,
    "00009" : 0,
    "00010" : 0,
    "00011" : 0,
    "00012" : 0,
    "00013" : 0,
    "00014" : 1,
    "00015" : 3,
    "00016" : 1,
    "00032" : 17,
    "00064" : 32263,
    "00128" : 43131,
    "00256" : 88619,
    "00512" : 17449,
    "01024" : 475
  }
}
```

**Changed clustering to (yyymm,ID)**

```
{
  "cluster_by_keys" : "LINEAR(yyyymm,ID)",
  "total_partition_count" : 953033,
  "total_constant_partition_count" : 769276,
  "average_overlaps" : 33.2017,
  "average_depth" : 18.5576,
  "partition_depth_histogram" : {
    "00000" : 0,
    "00001" : 768630,
    "00002" : 0,
    "00003" : 15,
    "00004" : 129,
    "00005" : 611,
    "00006" : 1589,
    "00007" : 3128,
    "00008" : 4235,
    "00009" : 5374,
    "00010" : 6404,
    "00011" : 6176,
    "00012" : 5809,
    "00013" : 5397,
    "00014" : 4034,
    "00015" : 3007,
    "00016" : 2287,
    "00032" : 18517,
    "00064" : 18992,
    "00128" : 43803,
    "00256" : 43519,
    "00512" : 11377
  }
}
```

**DISTINCT DATA**

```
yyymmd      1076. Distinct
ID          179030 Distinct
```

Comment: Based on the name of the column, the ID column would seem to have unique values or be a high cardinality column if there are multiple rows with the same ID value each row distinguished by a timestamp, version or something like that. Is this the case? Is the ID unique? If not unique, it is very high cardinality compared to the table overall?

Comment: There are multiple versions of each row for the same ID by timestamp and other columns having different values for the same ID and YYYMM

Comment: I found that as below
```Pruning
275,445 Partitions scanned
945,526 Partitions total```

Comment: Have you tried "cluster by (yyyymm, ID)" instead of "cluster by (ID, yyyymm)"?

ID is never a good candidate for clustering keys, but date is. Due to ID is the first clustering key, and its uniqueness might cause all data to be evenly distributed to all partitions, even if you have date in the clustering key.

Reverse the keys might help.

Comment: @EricLin Checking that now . After alter table to change cluster .. Should I do any clustering of data ? or is automatic?

Comment: I reverse the cluster key it took same time .. but I change the query to with clause and it reduced the time to 9 mins but still expecting more faster

Comment: @Karthik it will take some time to cluster a table.  My suggestion is to run a `INSERT OVERWRITE INTO` statement with an `ORDER BY ID` so that the data is pre-clustered.  Otherwise, make sure the clustering is actually done before testing.

Comment: What do you get from `system$clustering_information`? Can you add the output of that function to the question?

Comment: @Karthik When did you get the clustering information? As Mike mentioned, it can take sometime to get the table re-clustered to an optimal state. Since it has been a while, can you check the clustering information again?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes this depends on the cardinality of the clustered columns, I think this is pointed out in earlier comments.

Clustering keys work like partition variables, so ideally they should be defined for columns with a low cardinality of values.

See: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/tables-clustering-micropartitions.html

What you can do is check what the column depth and overlap is, as the link above illustrates. The closer you are to 1 depth and 0 overlap the better.

Use this commend to check the clustering columns, see: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/system_clustering_information.html

Always look at the table structure first!
There are two types of filtering when Snowflake analyzes a query to minimize the table scan (from your screenshot it appears this is where most of the time is spent in your query)

1. Static pruning - filters, ensure that you do not apply functions on the column itself but where you can apply functions on the static value of your query
2. Dynamic pruning - joins, try to use equijoins and conjunctive queries. Explicit column joins makes performance much better

Next is the appropriately sized Virtual Warehouse, on the right hand side of your query analyzer you should look for things like spillage and cache. Spillage indicates that the warehouse is not of an appropriate size. Too smaller and the content spills to remote storage.

Comment: Clustering Depth is 30

Comment: Updated the question with clustering information

Comment: You can see clustering by LINEAR(yyyymm,ID) is better than the other way around